# Creating a nested array from a flat array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I'm looking to create a nested array based on reading a flat array. An example of the flat array I am reading is this:

```
const flatItems = [
    {
        "code": "CODE1",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "question": "Question 1",
        "order": 0,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE2",
        "title": "Title 2",
        "question": "Question 2",
        "order": 1,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE3",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "question": "Question 3",
        "order": 2,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE4",
        "title": "Title 4",
        "question": "Question 4",
        "order": 3,
    },
];
```

And ideally I would like to place this into groups of 'Yes's and 'No's. The flat array is already in the correct order. There will only ever be one item in the 'Yes's but can have many in the 'No's depending on any conditions.

```
const treeItems = {
    question: "Question 1",
    options: [
        {
            value: "Yes",
            items: [
                {
                    code: "CODE1",
                    title: "Title 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            value: "No",
            question: "Question 2"
            options: [
                {
                    value: "Yes",
                    items: [
                        {
                            code: "CODE2",
                            title: "Title 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    value: "No",
                    items: [
                        {
                            code: "CODE3",
                            title: "Title 3"
                        },
                        {
                            code: "CODE4",
                            title: "Title 4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am aware that reduce may be the best approach here, but would anyone have any good examples or recommended practices as how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What are the rules here?  Why does `2` nest in `1`, and `3` nest in `2` but `4` does not nest in `3`?  Is there any information in `order` that is not supplied by the array index?  What happens to the strings `"Question 3"` and `"Question 4"`?  Are they just dropped?  I think we need more information here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group these items use "Yes" and "No" as the properties of the final object.
Using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) sounds solid in this case.

Not sure how you want to group because your JSON is inconsistent.

```js
const flatItems = [
    {
        "code": "CODE1",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "question": "Question 1",
        "order": 0,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE2",
        "title": "Title 2",
        "question": "Question 2",
        "order": 1,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE3",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "question": "Question 3",
        "order": 2,
    },
    {
        "code": "CODE4",
        "title": "Title 4",
        "question": "Question 4",
        "order": 3,
    },
];

const groupedObject = flatItems.reduce((tmpGroupedObject, item) => {
  const groupingProperty = item.order < 2 ? "Yes" : "No"; /// grouping decision
  if (!Array.isArray(tmpGroupedObject[groupingProperty])) {
    tmpGroupedObject[groupingProperty] = []; /// make Obj["Yes"] an array
  }
  tmpGroupedObject[groupingProperty].push(item);
  return tmpGroupedObject;
}, {});

console.log(groupedObject);
```

Comment: Note that your output does not match the expected output (not that I understand the expectation.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I know. Do you have a better term than "Not sure how you want to group because because your JSON is inconsistent." when answering these kind of questions?

Comment: No, and I'm not opposed to guesswork in answers, but I personally think the expected output is just too confused to actually try to answer here.  Kudos for trying, I guess.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks :)

Comment: ... and now I went and added my own answer.  :-)  I think I understand the output structure, although I'm guessing there's a mistake in the example.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm confused by the requested output.  I especially don't understand why `CODE3` and `CODE4` are on the same level, and not nested as another Yes/No pair.  But we can write a fairly simple recursion to do that:

```js
const convert = ([{code, title, question} = {}, ...items]) => ({
  question,
  options: [
    {value: "Yes", items: [{code, title}]},
    {value: "No", ... (items .length < 3 ? {items: items .map (({code, title}) => ({code, title}))} : convert (items))}
  ]
})

const flatItems = [{code: "CODE1", title: "Title 1", question: "Question 1", order: 0}, {code: "CODE2", title: "Title 2", question: "Question 2", order: 1}, {code: "CODE3", title: "Title 3", question: "Question 3", order: 2}, {code: "CODE4", title: "Title 4", question: "Question 4", order: 3}]

console .log (
  convert (flatItems)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

However by changing `< 3` to `< 2`, we get what I think of as a much more logical grouping:

```js
const convert = ([{code, title, question} = {}, ...items]) => ({
  question,
  options: [
    {value: "Yes", items: [{code, title}]},
    {value: "No", ... (items .length < 2 ? {items: items .map (({code, title}) => ({code, title}))} : convert (items))}
  ]
})

const flatItems = [{code: "CODE1", title: "Title 1", question: "Question 1", order: 0}, {code: "CODE2", title: "Title 2", question: "Question 2", order: 1}, {code: "CODE3", title: "Title 3", question: "Question 3", order: 2}, {code: "CODE4", title: "Title 4", question: "Question 4", order: 3}]

console .log (
  convert (flatItems)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```